# How to fix top level links in WordPress responsive menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using the JS below to make a WordPress menu responsive. Basically, it ads an "active" class to the parent of a menu item if there's an associated submenu. This works perfectly for the responsive menu, as clicking the parent expands the submenu. However, on the desktop version, the parent items are now un-clickable because instead of actually linking, the "active" class is added. Any help to make this function as is >768 but function without it at <768 would be greatly appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('nav#menu > ul > li').addClass('has-submenu');

  $('body').addClass('js');
    var $menu = $('#menu'),
      $menulink = $('.menu-link'),
      $menuTrigger = $('.has-submenu > a');

  $menulink.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $menulink.toggleClass('active');
    $menu.toggleClass('active');
  });

  $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the height by doing the following:

```
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
```

Then you can use a conditional statement for height:

```
if (viewportHeight >= 768) {
  //+++ desktop
} else { 
  //+++ mobile
}
```

Documentation for jQuery [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/).